# Unable to select image using flutter image picker on iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am learning how to select images from gallery. I have implemented flutter image picker for the same. But when I try to select the image in simulator, I am not able to do so.

Please help

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.3.pre, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

My code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Play(),
    // theme: ThemeData.dark(),
  ));
}

class Play extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayState createState() => _PlayState();
}

class _PlayState extends State<Play> {
  File _file;

  ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  PickedFile _pickedFile;

  Future _getImageFromGallery() async {
    print("Getting Image from Gallery.");
    _pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(_pickedFile.path);
    setState(() {
      _file = File(_pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  Future _getImageFromCamera() async {
    print("Getting Image from Camera.");
    _pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _file = File(_pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Play"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onLongPress: _getImageFromCamera,
                onPressed: _getImageFromGallery,
                child: Text("Get Image")),
          ),
          _file != null
              ? Image.file(
                  _file,
                  height: 200,
                )
              : Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  size: 100,
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using M1 Mac air. I have switched to beta channel to get rid of some verbose error.
**Everything is working fine. Just, when I click on an image nothing happens. It doesn't get selected.**

Comment: Have any issue you faces when try upload image?

Comment: And have you add Camera permissions on your `ios/info.plist` ?

Comment: yes I have added `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Need to access gallery in order to get image.</string>
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Need to access camera in order to get image.</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Add photo liabrary description</string>`

Comment: same code works perfectly on windows

Comment: I have the same issue. did you find any solution

Comment: Same here. Mac Mini M1.
Same code works fine on Android.

Comment: Same here, on M1 MacBook pro. It's been a roadblock since i don't have any physical IOS device to test the App. Let me know if anyone has a workaround.

Comment: Same Issue .Open Gallery but unable to select image using flutter image_picker: 0.7.3 on iOS simulator. I have MacBook pro.

Comment: Same issue. I believe it has to do something with the latest version of XCode or M1 chip.

Comment: The same issue, must be something to do with the M1 chip. Can't run a fluent Android simulator nor iOS Simulator works perfectly.

Comment: Chiming in here:  Same exact issue.  M1 Mac Mini.

Comment: Same issue with the M1 machine, is it related to M1

Comment: Same here, any news ?

Comment: you could not use camera  in simulator but only in real device in usb link or wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works on my simulator:

[image]

There are discussions online including [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78391#issuecomment-825054060), that this could be an Apple bug and no known workaround.

In fact, there are people in [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672449) reports this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on iOS 17. I fixed it by adding the following line into info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your photo library to pick an image for your profile.</string>
```

If you are accessing the camera you also need to add these

```
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
```